# spring 3, tiles - JSp page loses all CSS effects after back or refresh

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I have a spring 3 + tiles application with spring security and stuff in place. Unfortunately when I login a user (authenticate) and forward to a login home page, it all looks great, but when I refresh the same page I loose all the CSS UI stuff and page is plain text and all UI elements are scattered.

any help is appreciated

my tiles.xml looks like

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/views/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/login_header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="welcome" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/login_header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definition>
```

my layout.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src=<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"/>></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/> media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Actual page after user login looks something like below
[image: Actual page]

After I refresh the same page, my page looks like this
[image: Messed up page after refresh]

Comment: Any errors in the chrome console (F12)?

Comment: Hey, its weird, I didnt notice these errors happening before, but yes I got the error

GET http://localhost:8090/resources/css/style.css 403 (Access is denied) home:7
GET http://localhost:8090/resources/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js 403 (Access is denied)

Answer (score 0):

WIth  help of @w4rumy I figured the issue, its because my local resources are not accessible due to a wrong spring security access.I had `<sec:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>` which should have been `<sec:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>`